# problem with ngModelOptions : value in ngmodel don't update in some cases

Tags: angular, typescript, input, pipe, ngmodel

I have some problems in input, I had the directive [ngModelOptions] because I want to update after "blur", because of pipe in [ngModel].  It works when I change the value in [ngModel], but if for example, I enter a value in a first, if I edit the input with the same, there are no update, and so pipe is not applied.

HTML:

```
<input
 (keypress)="limiterRemise($event)"
 [ngClass]="{
   'form-control-plaintext': !selected && datas.Focus,
   'form-control': selected && datas.Focus,
   'without-border' : !datas.Focus,
   'error-line': remiseErreur 
 }" 
 class="text-center col-md-4 gray"
 [ngModel]="datas.Remise | number: '1.2-2' : 'fr' " 
 (ngModelChange)="remiseChange($event, datas,gamme )" 
 [placeholder]="datas.Remise | number: '1.2-2': 'fr'"
 type="number"
 min="0"
 [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
 (click)="selectGamme(gamme)"  
/>
```

some screens of my problem:

[On initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnhiJ.png)

[After update with same value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMCgo.png)

[After update with other value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCm8m.png)

thanks.

Comment: Could you please add some `stackblitz` example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `(input)` event listener. This may help you detect changes for each user input.